# Connection interrupted by other software on your computer

Tags: pidgin, lotus-sametime

I'm currently using Pidgin 2.10.4 and we have Sametime 8.5.2.

Everything worked OK till about a day ago I started getting "Lost connection with server. Connection interrupted by other software on your computer"

I'm not sure what other software it could be talking about. Has someone else seen this and able to fix it? If so what do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the file `accounts.xml` which should be in one of these locations:

   - C:\Users\**YOUR USER NAME**\AppData\Roaming\.purple\
   - C:\Users\**YOUR USER NAME**\AppData
2. Edit it, and in the settings section, try this:

   ```
   <settings>
       <setting name='server' type='string'>YOURSERVERNAME</setting>
       <setting name='client_major' type='int'>30</setting>
       <setting name='port' type='int'>1533</setting>
       <setting name='client_minor' type='int'>8511</setting>
       <setting name='fake_client_id' type='bool'>1</setting>
       <setting name='force_login' type='bool'>0</setting>
       <setting name='client_id_val' type='int'>4676</setting>
   </settings>
   ```